# Can we call POM from cypress custom command

Tags: cypress, pom.xml, cypress-custom-commands

I was wondering if we could call a page object model from a cypress custom commands. If this can happen then it could make cypress automated test more powerful

Comment: It can be done easily with importing your page object.

Comment: Can u add a bit of code snippet. Forexample login page called on custom command made for login

Comment: It's simple. Add `import {login} from '/path/to/login/login.js'` at top of your `commands.js` file. I recommendi reading up more on importing. https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-import-class-from-another-file